# Steam item giveaway/trading thread

Tags: discussion, community

With Steam now giving away games as part of the [Holiday Sale](http://store.steampowered.com/holidaysale/), a lot of us are bound to end up with extra copies of games.  Instead of letting them sit around our Steam Inventories, let's spread them out among other Gaming members.

Add an answer with the games you're trying to trade, the games you're willing to give away, and/or the games you're looking for.  In the comments of other people's answers, propose trades for your own stuff.

Please keep your lists up to date!

**Also please list your coupon's usage and expiration dates!**

Answer (score 12):

**Free**

- Deathmatch Classic
- Half-Life 2: Deathmatch

**Trade**

- Half-Life 2/HL2:Lost Coast (Pack)
- Left 4 Dead 2
- Cogs
- Orange Box

Comment: I wonder if [coupons stack](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43326/do-steam-coupons-stack) (e.g. whether a second 25% one would yield a total 44% discount)

Comment: @InsidiousForce Sent!

Comment: thanks a bunch!

Comment: would like to get l4d2, all I have is - Bit Trip Beat
Robo Blitz -
Humble Bundle 3 Steam Key - any interest in some kind of a trade?

Comment: @InsidiousForce I've already got BTB and HIB3.  If you could throw in some coal or something with Robo Blitz, I could probably make that trade happen.

Comment: sorry i didn't notice this until now

Answer (score 5):

I have a bunch of retail-style keys for things I already had from the Indie Royale bundles.  (Unlike the Humble Bundle, the Indie Royale guys have [said on Twitter](https://twitter.com/#!/indieroyale/status/130579144076570624) that their codes can be regifted...) I'm happy to trade for them, I'm not sure what's equivalent value.  (Some of the cheap things from my [Steam wishlist](http://steamcommunity.com/id/mmastertheone/wishlist/), maybe?)

## Trade

- Ben There, Dan That! & Time Gentlemen, Please!
- Breath of Death VII
- Bunch of Heroes
- Critical Mass
- Cthulhu Saves The World
- Fate of the World: Denial DLC
- Fate of the World: Extras Pack DLC
- Fate of the World: Migration DLC
- Greed Corp
- Hacker Evolution: Duality
- Hacker Evolution: Untold
- Hoard
- Hoard: Dynomite Roll!
- Hoard: Flame Broiled SANDwich
- InMomentum
- Lume
- Nimbus
- Sanctum
- Sanctum: Killing Floor DLC
- Sanctum: Penetrator DLC
- Sanctum: Violator DLC
- Your Doodles Are Bugged! x2
- Zombie Shooter 1
- Zombie Shooter 2

Comment: Btw, the *Breath of Death VII* & *Cthulhu Saves The World* is the same key, so you can't trade them separately.

Comment: @mordi2k Normally I would agree with you, but in this case they appear to have given me separate retail codes for each, so I'm not sure that's actually true...

Comment: Oh, my bad then. I just assumed it, since the Indie Royale keys I got, were the same for both games :)

Comment: Would you send me the Eufloria coupon? it'd be awesome if I could get it in the next 10 hours :) -- [my steam](http://steamcommunity.com/id/kromak) (If not, no worries, I'll buy it anyway)

Comment: If Juan already gets a Eufloria coupon elsewhere, could I get it before the sale's over? :P

Comment: @JuanManuel Add me on Steam (mmastertheone in the Steam group) in the next hour and I'll gift it to you.  After that I'm going to bed.  ;)

Comment: @Ullallulloo, I did, in fact, get it from [mordi2k](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/3594/14) -- I think I'm in a very different timezone from Margaret :)

Answer (score 5):

**Free**

- <del>Half-Life 2</del>
- Killing Floor guest pass (2 copies)
- Any TF2 crate in [my inventory](http://steamcommunity.com/id/yvh11a/inventory)

**Trade**

- Any duplicates in my TF2 inventory

Comment: If Half-Life 2 is still available, I'll take it. Send it to my SE email.

Comment: @Professor - will do

Comment: What is a Killing Floor guest pass exactly?

Comment: @Squeaky A guest pass allows you to play the full game for three whole days.

Comment: @Squeaky - no idea but I have two of them

Comment: @Professor - I can't see your SE email on your profile...have I missed it?

Comment: @SteveV. Really? Just send it to prof.turtal(at)gmail.com then.

Comment: @Professor - done

Comment: @SteveV. Thanks!

Comment: @Professor User emails are only visible to mods, I believe.

Comment: I was wondering if I could have the Skyrim coupon (if you're not planning to use it). This is my Steam profile: http://steamcommunity.com/id/kromak

Comment: @JuanManuel - sure.  If you haven't received it within 24 hours, ask me again (because I probably forgot)

Comment: Pinging you after 24 hours as requested. -- thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

### Trade

- [Anything in my TF2 backpack](http://tf2b.com/id/lamb021), for a reasonable offer.
- Train Simulator 2012!!!!11!!!!111!!one!!!111!!
- RUSH

### Free

**Games people should have played**

- Half Life 2
- Half Life 2: Episode 1

**Coupons**

- -50% Valve.
- -50% Wings of Prey
- -50% Costume Quest
- -50% X3:Gold

**TF2 Weapons!**

I have a... small collection of TF2 weapons in my alt. I'll happily send people things they're missing, to a reasonable extent. (If you are looking for particular vintages, I also probably have it. Unless it's one of the recent ones.)

- Ali Baba's Wee Booties x 4
- Ambassador x 2
- Amputator x 5
- Atomizer
- Axtinguisher x 4
- Back Scratcher x 6
- Backburner x 2
- Battalion's Backup x 4
- Big Earner
- Black Box x 2
- Blutsauger
- Bonk! Atomic Punch x 8
- Boston Basher x 8
- Brass Beast x 4
- Buff Banner x 3
- Buff Banner (Gifted)
- Buffalo Steak Sandvich x 2
- Bushwacka x 5
- Candy Cane x 5
- Chargin' Targe
- Claidheamh MÃ²r x 7
- Cloak and Dagger x 5
- Concheror x 8
- Conniver's Kunai x 5
- Crit-a-Cola x 4
- Crusader's Crossbow
- Dalokohs Bar x 3
- Darwin's Danger Shield x 4
- Dead Ringer x 5
- Degreaser x 5
- Detonator
- Direct Hit x 2
- Equalizer x 2
- Eviction Notice
- Eyelander x 5
- Family Business x 3
- Fan O'War x 2
- Fists of Steel x 3
- Flare Gun
- Force-A-Nature x 2
- Frontier Justice x 2
- Frying Pan x 3
- Gloves of Running Urgently x 2
- Gunboats x 5
- Gunslinger x 4
- Gunslinger (Gifted)
- Half-Zatoichi x 3
- Holy Mackerel x 5
- Homewrecker x 4
- Huntsman x 3
- Jag x 6
- Jarate x 4
- Killing Gloves of Boxing x 2
- Kritzkrieg x 2
- L'Etranger x 6
- Liberty Launcher x 4
- Loch-n-Load x 2
- Mad Milk
- Mantreads
- Natascha x 4
- Overdose x 4
- Pain Train x 3
- Persian Persuader
- Powerjack x 3
- Quick-Fix
- Razorback x 5
- Righteous Bison
- Sandman x 4
- Sandvich x 5
- Scotsman's Skullcutter x 6
- Scottish Resistance x 5
- Shortstop x 4
- Soda Popper x 2
- Solemn Vow x 3
- Southern Hospitality x 5
- Sydney Sleeper x 3
- Tomislav
- Tribalman's Shiv x 5
- Ubersaw x 3
- Ullapool Caber x 4
- Vita-Saw x 4
- Warrior's Spirit x 2
- Winger x 2
- Wrangler x 5
- Your Eternal Reward x 4

Comment: So I should play HL2?  I'll take those off your hands, if you don't mind.  :)

Comment: I'd love to take a ton of those items off your hands. How many are you willing to send?

Comment: Missing a few of the TF2 items. If you're really helping people fill out their inventories, please friend me (kenkoukotsu) to set up a trade. Thanks!

Comment: I just started playing TF2, so I will take any item you will give me. I am on Steam at http://steamcommunity.com/id/murgatroid99/

Comment: I could use a couple TF2 items. :) http://steamcommunity.com/id/Ullallulloo/

Comment: If your HL2/HL2:E1 are still up for free, I'll take them off your hands! ... Only thing I have spare if you want is Steel Storm Burning Retribution, but, this was in a bundle recently, so, you probably already have it... if there is anything else you want, let me know.

Comment: In case you couldn't tell, my earlier comment was a humble request for HL2 and HL2:E1.  :)

Answer (score 4):

Free:

- Portal

Trade:

- Cogs
- Left 4 Dead
- Left 4 Dead 2

Comment: Would you be willing to part with L4D for Terraria? L4D is the only Valve game I don't own, and Terraria is the only game I have to spare.

Comment: Unfortunately, I already own Terraria.

Comment: Yeah I figured you did, pretty much everyone does.

Comment: Is the Portal give-away offer still valid? :)

Comment: @user1338062 Sure is!

Answer (score 4):

### Trade

- The Longest Journey + Dreamfall

Comment: For starters, please link to your backpack so people know for sure which one's yours.  Second, no one will be notified by your @lerts because they aren't in comments.  Since you need 19 more rep to post comments just anywhere, I'll add a few comments on the relevant people's answers for you. :) Third, I only have a 33% percent off any Valve title, and 50% off Cogs and only Cogs.  Either one of which you can have if you want, but fyi.

Comment: I can give you my 50% off Steam coupon. I think I need your Steam name, then I can send it when I am done with work.

Comment: @murgatroid99 either the email adress or the Steam community profile name (which is not the Steam user name, FYI)

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I don't know how to do it that way. Steam's FAQ describes transferring the coupon with Steam Trading, which does use the user name.

Comment: @murgatroid99 [these](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6748-ETSG-5417)? Yes, they mean the name that you give to your Steam Community Profile. It can (and should) be different from your User name (that with which you log in to Steam) and is publicly visible. Also, badp asked a question about trading with strangers: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/31055/88

Comment: @Squeaky you should keep your SteamID secret! The only thing others ever need is your profile name... You'd better delete that comment as soon as you get the coupon

Comment: @TobiasKienzler I'm not entirely sure that's a valid concern.  While it's not necessary for a trade, it's not any private information.  Nothing extremely useful can be done with a steam ID.  In fact, you can get the steam IDs of anyone connected to a source engine game server

Comment: @DaveMcClelland still it's one step closer to a hijacked account...

Comment: @dancek Sounds good; sorry I didn't reply to your chat, I was afk - tend to leave Steam on whilst it's downloading stuff. Some games would be good if that's ok with you.

Answer (score 3):

**Trade:**

- [Droplitz](http://store.steampowered.com/app/23120/)

I will trade for any game on my [wishlist](http://steamcommunity.com/id/murgatroid99/wishlist).

Comment: What would you want for Achron?

Comment: @JuanManuel I don't really want anything you are trading. If nobody else wants it in a few days I could just give it to you.

Comment: @JuanManuel I guess I would trade for anything on my wishlist.

Comment: Ok, that would be great :) -- I will update my post as I get my hands on more things, I'm just starting with the objectives.

Comment: Could you add a link to your steam profile or wishlist?

Comment: @JuanManuel It's in the post now

Comment: @MatthewRead I am pretty sure that you can't gift the coupons; you have to trade them in steam. So if you trade me I will give it to you.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I don't really have anything to trade that I wouldn't rather give to someone who'd use it :/ but thanks.

Comment: @MatthewRead I just meant that the transfer has to go through the Steam trading system. I can just trade it for nothing to give it to you for free.

Comment: I see, my bad.  I've added you.

Comment: Thank you again!

Comment: Could I have that SEGA coupon, please? I wants me some Sonic Generations. All this talk about how it's not completely terrible got me curious.

Comment: @lunboks sure. I just need to trade with you in Steam.

Answer (score 3):

## Trade (Games)

- [Oddworld: Stranger's Wrath](http://store.steampowered.com/app/15750/)
- [Cthulhu Saves the World & Breath of Death VII Double Pack](http://store.steampowered.com/sub/8848/)
- [Blocks That Matter](http://store.steampowered.com/app/111800)

## Looking for... (but not exclusively)

- Fallout 3 (non-German)
- Fallout: New Vegas (non-German)
- Bioshock (non-German)

Answer (score 3):

**Free:**

**Trade:**

Alien vs. Predator: The Game

Comment: I'll take HE:Duality :)

Comment: @JohntheGreen Sorry, gave it to a friend literally 15 minutes after I added it here :(

Answer (score 2):

Free:

- <del>Terraria</del>

Trades:

- <del>Crazy Machines 1.5</del>
- [TF2 Backpack](http://steamcommunity.com/id/thepugs/inventory/#440)

Comment: hey Ian, is that Two Worlds 2 coupon the same as all the others? (i.e. only good starting Jan 2nd.)

Comment: @yx. yup - seems like all the coupons they're issuing are for after the Holiday sale.

Comment: laaaaaaaaame :(

Comment: @IanPugsley: No, some coupons are gold and can be used anytime.

Comment: @Ullallulloo oh gotcha - editing.

Comment: I am interested in Terraria. Is there anything in [my inventory](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198047581965/inventory/#440) that you want?

Comment: @John not particularly, atm; if you wanna post an answer with whatever you have for trade and update it when that changes, I'll keep an eye on it. :)

Comment: Done.  Although I find it unlikely that it will ever contain anything but TF2 items and coupons.  :P

Comment: What would you be willing to take for Terraria? I have 5 coupons and a copy of Uplink.

Answer (score 2):

Free TF2 items:

- The Frying Pan
- Ellis' Cap

Comment: [Squeaky would like your 50% off voucher.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/3583/5029) I'm adding this comment for him because he can't yet.  Please comment on his answer to complete the deal.  :)

Comment: Could I get the frying pan?  And maybe the cap?  I don't know if I have anything of interest: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/3604/144

Comment: Sure! How can I contact you on Steam? I am peter_witthoff---at---hotmail.com. You can have all my TF2 stuff, I don't play it. I'll happily take a random game off your hands (you can pick).

Comment: @victoriah Are you findable in the Gaming.SE Steam group?  It might be easiest to add each other as friends then do things that way.  This is me: http://steamcommunity.com/id/mmastertheone

Answer (score 2):

### Trade*

*If you don't have a lot of rep, I'll just ask you for some scrap metal.

- Portal
- Half Life 2

Comment: Did the listed coupons expire at the beginning of March? If so, please remove it from your list so it is up to date

Answer (score 2):

### Trade

- If you're interested in TF2 items, feel free to [browse my backpack](http://steamcommunity.com/id/agent86/inventory/#440) and make a reasonable offer.  Probably some of them I'd be willing to part with for free, if you've got a hankering for something that isn't worth much.

Comment: [Squeaky would like your 50% off voucher.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/3583/5029) I'm adding this comment for him because he can't yet.  Please comment on his answer to complete the deal.  :)

Comment: @John Argh, I didn't get a notification for this, sorry Squeaky :(  I still have the coupon in case you've not gotten one already.

Comment: Did the listed coupons expire at the beginning of March? If so, please remove them from your list so it is up to date

Answer (score 2):

**Trade:**

- 33% off of a Valve Purchase. (effective January 2nd onward)
- Humble bundle 3 (Crayon Physics Deluxe, Cogs, VVVVVV, Hammerfight, And Yet It Moves)

Comment: Did the listed coupon expire at the beginning of March? If so, please remove them from your list so it is up to date

Answer (score 2):

**Trade:**

- <strike>Rock of Ages</strike>
- <strike>- Portal 2</strike>
- Garshasp: The Monster Slayer
- <strike>The Orange Box</strike>
- -33% Valve (Publisher) (Post holiday - Mars)
- <strike>-25% Activision (Publisher) (Post holiday - Mars)</strike>
- <strike>-25%  Sega (Publisher) (Post holiday - Mars)</strike>
- TF2 Stuff

**Free**

- -50% Greed Corp (Game) (Post holiday - Mars)
- -50% Penny Arcade Adventure Combopack (Game) (Post holiday - mars)

I prefer to trade for coal but exceptions can be made. (I am a gambler in heart and soul lol)

[My inventory](http://steamcommunity.com/id/hrx/inventory)

Comment: how much coal you looking for portal 2?

Comment: How does 3 coal sound to you?

Comment: sure.  search for email hyperlink.teltura(at)gmail(dot)com, steam name teltura.  I'm also in the GSE steam group.

Comment: How much coal would you want for Rock of Ages?

Comment: Sorry its gone, most ppl add me on steam right away so the stuff goes fast :(

Comment: Did the listed coupon expire at the beginning of March? If so, please remove it from your list so it is up to date

Answer (score 2):

**Free**

- Holiday Sale 2011 Gift - Half-Life 2: Episode One:

  - Includes 4 items: Half-Life 2: Deathmatch, Half-Life 2: Lost Coast, Half-Life Deathmatch: Source, Half-Life 2: Episode One

**Trade**

- [Recettear](http://store.steampowered.com/app/70400/)

Comment: hey, I'll take AaAaAa if you don't want it; cogs, too, if no one wants it.  steam: ketura01 email: hyperlink.teltura(at)gmail(dot)com

Comment: Willing to trade a piece or two of coal for AaAaAA if you're willing. Let me know.

Comment: @Ketura I'm going to give Kotsu AaAaAA and you Cogs if that's okay, so I can split it up a little. :)

Comment: @Kotsu Sure, that's fine! This is my Steam name, feel free to add me so we can trade.

Comment: That sounds fair to me!

Comment: @Ketura I sent it to your email that you listed, hopefully it's in your inbox!

Comment: @Ketura Did you receive Cogs? It says you've still not accepted it yet.

Comment: I have not, come to think of it.  I figured it was just a delay due to the servers sucking.  I've received other gifts; perhaps try resending?  hyperlink.teltura(at)gmail(dot)com

Comment: @Ketura Resent!

Comment: awesome!  it went through this time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Free**
2 Killing floor guest passes (Not from the summer sale, just bought the game and they came with it)

**Trade**
[Poker Night at the Inventory](http://store.steampowered.com/app/31280/)

Answer (score 0):

**TRADE**

- Various things in my [Team Fortress 2
  inventory](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198022109193/inventory/#440).
  I won't trade away any special promotion items (companion cube pin,
  Genuine Pip-Boy, et cetera). Send me a message if anything else
  interests you, and I'll let you know if I'm willing to trade it.

Answer (score 0):

Would like:

HalfLife 2 Ep. 1

Giving Away/Up for trade

50% off Assassin's Creed: Revelations (Expires April 1st)

Answer (score 0):

I've got a copy of **Section 8: Prejudice** to trade for some other nice game - no TF2-stuff or coupons!

Answer (score 0):

[H]ave these Humble Bundle Steam **Keys**:
- Alpha Prime 
- ARMA: Cold War Assault 
- **Bastion** 
- Batman™: Arkham Origins **DLC** 
- **F.E.A.R.** 
- Fish Fillets 2 
- **FTL: Faster Than Light** 
- **Magicka + 2 DLC** 
- Take On Helicopters 
[H]ave this Steam **Gift**: 
- Aerena

[W]ant:
Other Keys, Cards, offer me something...

The Keys will be sent as an **Humble Bundle Gift e-mail**. 
The Gift is tradable in Steam.

For reference, [My Games](http://steamcommunity.com/id/Tonxabar/games/?tab=all) and [My Wishlist](http://steamcommunity.com/id/Tonxabar/wishlist/).

Thank  you for reading...